# Xcode-developing not for Mac only?

Tags: xcode, macos, osx-snow-leopard

Is it possible to make a non-Mac/iOS application with Xcode? Or if it is impossible, can you suggest any other environment to an ultimate noob?
P.S.: I have Snow Leopard on my Mac.
P.P.S: I think, I asked a wrong question. Everything started with one problem: C++ environment with debug function for Mac. Xcode is just a variant.

Comment: It's not available with default Xcode installation, but there are/were some tools which let you build for other platforms from Xcode. Specifying which platforms and languages you are interested in would help you get an answer if there is one.

Answer (score 0):

You can install a cross compiling gcc suit. However I'm not sure if that makes sense with Objective-C as you would need to restrict yourself to non apple APIs (like Gnu Step).

I would suggest to learn Java instead and use an IDE like Eclipse (or any other cost free IDE like IDEA IntelliJ or NetBeans).